# Using a for loop to cube list python

Tags: python

I can't seem to get this cubed list to display as a list on pyhton

```
# use range function to generate a list as below
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

RangeList = list(range(2,11,2))
RangeList
# [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]

# use a for loop and the 'cubed' function defined to convert the above list to
# [8, 64, 216, 512, 1000]


for x in RangeList:
    cubed(x)
```

How can i get the results of this code to appear as a list format rather than :

```
(2, 8)
(4, 64)
(6, 216)
(8, 512)
(10, 1000)
```

Comment: How have you defined `cubed`?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are very clear actually:

```
# use a for loop ... 
for i in range(len(RangeList)):
    # ... and the 'cubed' function to convert the above list 
    RangeList[i] = cubed(RangeList[i])
```

Note that the plain `cubed(RangeList[i])` just returns a value, but does not change the list element. That's what the assignment `RangeList[i] = ...` is for.

Comment: The output he's getting suggests that `cubed()` prints its result, it doesn't return it.

Comment: So that will need to be fixed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why use cubed function when you can do it easily with for loop only? Iterate the list, find the cube of the element using `**3` or `math.pow(element,3)`. After that, create a tuple which contains element and it's cube and append this tuple to a list. After the whole loop is completed, print the list containing cubes. Your code:

```
rangelist=list(range(2,11,2))
list1=[]
for i in rangelist:
    x=i**3
    v=(i,x)                     #creating tuple
    list1.append(v)
for i in list1:               #loop for printing tuples
    print(i)
```